# What does this mean?: Columns("B:IV").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you will help me to learn the meaning of this line:

> Columns("B:IV").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Comment: Please do some effort (search for an answer, google, etc) before asking such questions.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, columns `B,C,D,E,F,.....,Z,AA,AB,AC,.....,IS,IT,IU,IV`
all of those will be deleted and they will be replaced with empty columns pulled from the left side of the sheet, meaning that if you have some data on column A that column will not be affected.

Comment: did you get the answer you are looking for? If so, please accept

Answer (score 0):

Columns("B:IV").Delete deletes the columns.
The shift to the left part shifts the remaining columns to the left. That code is not necessary since the shift to the left is the default.